# Custom opacity Plotly candlesticks

Tags: plotly, opacity, candlestick-chart

I would like to know if we can change the opacity of the candlesticks so that they are the same color as the edges ?

[like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvfvP.png)

[not like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axMTo.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- used https://plotly.com/python/candlestick-charts/#simple-candlestick-with-pandas to have a MWE
- simple case of explicitly setting **fillcolor** and **line_color** for **increasing** and **decreasing**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv"
)
df = df.head(8)
fig = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Candlestick(
            x=df["Date"],
            open=df["AAPL.Open"],
            high=df["AAPL.High"],
            low=df["AAPL.Low"],
            close=df["AAPL.Close"],
        )
    ]
)


fig.update_xaxes(rangebreaks=[{"pattern": "day of week", "bounds": [6, 1]}])

fig.update_traces(
    {
        d: {"fillcolor": c, "line": {"color": c}}
        for d, c in zip(["increasing", "decreasing"], ["red", "green"])
    }
)
```

[image]